# In RxJS or Redux Observable does debounceTime also act as a delay

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

On user click I want a badge to show for 3 seconds (i.e. the badge should automatically hide after 3 seconds). I also only want a single SHOW_BADGE action to register until the badge hides. I think debounceTime is good for this, however, the time until hide has become inconsistent when I click multiple times.

Does debounceTime extend the delay? Is debounceTime a delay in itself? How would I fix the example below to get what I want?

```
export const badgeEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('SHOW_BADGE')
   .pipe(
      debounceTime(3000),
      delay(3000),
      mapTo({ type: 'HIDE_BADGE' })
    );
```

As suggested by someone in the comments below auditTime solves this particular issue. Here is the final code for the badge epic.

```
export const badgeEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('SHOW_BADGE'),
    auditTime(3000),
    mapTo({ type: 'HIDE_BADGE' })
  );
```

Comment: Yes, it expands the delay. In other words, it makes a delay from the last emission as its described here http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime. Maybe what you're looking for is [`auditTime`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime)

Comment: You could check if badge is already shown before calling an action or before using `.pipe` in action.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem is? `debounceTime` alone should ensure that the given amount of time has passed after the last click. The delay only extends that time. In your example to 6 seconds.

Comment: @Yoshi Sure. I would like a badge to appear when a user clicks a button. The badge should automatically hide after 3 seconds which I should've made clear in the opening post. I don't want any user action to extend the delay.

Comment: So regardless of any other action coming in, even if it's `'SHOW_BADGE'` again, 3 seconds after the first occurrence the badge should *hide again*?

Comment: @Yoshi Yes, that's right.

Comment: @martin Looks like auditTime solves it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you're up to, you could do that every time `SHOW_BADGE` comes in before the delay times out, the previous epic cancels itself. This way `HIDE_BADGE` will always get called 3 seconds after the last click:

```
export const badgeEpic = action$ =>
  actions$.pipe(
    ofType('SHOW_BADGE'),
    switchMap(() =>
      of(({ type: 'HIDE_BADGE' })).pipe(
        delay(3000),
        takeUntil(action$.ofType('SHOW_BADGE')),
      )),
  )
```

As pointed by @Yoshi, `takeUntil` might not be necessary as `switchMap` cancels previously running inner observable.

Comment: Do you even need the `takeUntil`? The `switchMap` *cancels* the previous delay when a new `'SHOW_BADGE'` comes in.

Comment: @Yoshi I had that piece of code working for me but seems that you could be right.

Comment: Super! Just getting this error: `ofType is not defined`. Where should I be importing ofType from?

Comment: import {ofType} from redux-observable